# Should magit revert a buffer after I discard a change from it when magit-auto-revert-mode is t?

Tags: magit

With magit 1.4.1, I have magit-auto-revert-mode set to t. When I visit a file in a buffer, make a change and save, then call magit-status and run magit-discard-item on the modified file, then switch back to the buffer, I would expect not to see the change, ie, I'd expect the buffer to have been reverted since I discarded the change. But that's not the case. I still see the change. Is this the expected behavior or a bug?

Comment: The file should be reverted. When you get back to the file-visiting buffer check whether Emacs itself thinks that the file has been modified on disk - there should be an M near the beginning of the mode-line.

Comment: Yes, the M is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known issue when using Magit 1.4.1 together with Emacs 24.5. It was fixed on `master` a few weeks ago and I have now also created a release, `1.4.2`, which includes that fix.

*NOTE: Magit 2.1.0 has been released, replacing the mode `magit-auto-revert-mode` with the option `magit-revert-buffers`. Like `1.4.2`, `2.1.0` does not have the issue that `1.4.1.` had on Emacs `24.5`.*